# Replacing image in css

Tags: css, overflow, font-size, text-indent

Most common method for "removing" text from elements was using `text-indent: -9999px`, but now I've read that it's better to use

```
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

so that browser doesn't have to create that 9999px box. But why can't we just use `font-size: 0`? What is exactly wrong with using this method?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/142-hiding-things-with-css/

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you. I personally use text-indent as a title as well, so while the page is loading the CSS document, the text will be a placeholder until the CSS has loaded. Also whenever I do 'text-indent: -9999px' I don't see any performance change whatsoever.

Basically, there isn't really any considerable disadvantage on using 'font-size: 0' or 'text-indent: -9999px' they both work just as well.

Comment: That did not answer OP's question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply. I guess that there aren't any noticeable performance issues with using `text-indent: -9999px`, it's just something I've read. I guess `text-indent: -9999px` is better since `font-size: 0` can reduce the height of the elements, if it's not predefined.

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers handle it differently, and there's too many variations for me to list them out. Some common problems is browsers that don't know what to do with  a rule like `font-size:0` and display the text as if no font-size rule was written. In other situations the text might be still visible just not all that readable. While other browsers (mozilla, netscape7) does what you want and doesn't show the text

Without testing `font-size:0` I'd guess the margin and paddings are still visible, though that's probably a problem in both cases.

Personally i'd even use `rgba` and set the opacity to `0.0` before trying `font-size:0`

Comment: I've tried `font-size: 0` in every modern browser + IE8 + safari for windows and it worked almost perfectly everywhere (height of the element was reduces in IE8). I guess it might not work in older browsers but lets face it, we don't care about those older (<IE8) browsers. And I think `rgba` is not better when comapred to `font-size: 0` since IE8 doesn't even support `rgba`, right?

Comment: very fair points actually, though i googled abit for more examples and here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/fonts/qt/tipfont0.htm. "IE for Mac and Safari: the text is displayed at the default size as if there were no font-size property". Though I'm not sure when the article is from